# Worried that my parents information might not match

Tags: visas, uk

In a previous UK visa application I entered my father year of birth as 1964. My visa was approved. Now I am applying for a skilled worker visa and I realized that my father is actually 1966. Should I be worried that the ECO would refuse my visa because the dates do not match?

Comment: Do they ask your parents DOB in skilled worker visa?

Comment: Yes they do. I was also surprised to see it.